# Parametric trajectory equation?

Tags: java, physics

I'm creating a very very simple game for fun. Realizing I needed the trajectory of an object given an angle and a velocity, it seemed logical to use this parametric equation:
x = (v*cos(ø))t and y = (v*sin(ø)t - 16t^2
I know that this equation works for a trajectory, but it isn't working with most ø values I use. 
Do java angles work any differently from normal angle calculation?
My goal is for the object to start from bottom left of the window and follow an arc that is determined by the speed and angle given. However it tends to go strange directions.

The value of ø should be horizontal at 0 degrees and vertical at 90, and in the equation it refers to the angle at which the arc begins.

This is my first ever question post on this site, so if I'm missing anything in that regard please let me know.

Here is the calculating part of my code

not shown is the void time() that counts for each 5ms
also I should mention that the parX and parY are used to refer to the x and y coordinates in an unrounded form, as graphics coordinates require integer values.
Any help is much appreciated, and thank you in advance!

```
public void parametric()
{
    parX = (float) ((speed*cos(-ø))*time);
    gravity = (time*time)*(16);
    parY = (float) ((float) ((speed*sin(-ø))*time)+gravity)+500;

    xCoord = round(parX);
    yCoord = round(parY);






}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do java angles work any differently from normal angle calculation?

You only need to read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos%28double%29)

```
public static double cos(double a)

Parameters:
a - an angle, in radians.
```

I guess you are using degrees instead of radians?

Comment: I simply was wondering if angles started at anything other than 0. I know the y axis, for example, is flipped, and I am wondering if this corresponds to angles as well.

Comment: The angles seem to give random values, and the trig functions seem to be the likely culprits. It may make a proper arc at 15 degrees, but not at 20, and so forth. It will go many different directions.

Comment: I don't want to be dense, but: are you using degrees or radians?